# HTTP status message not properly returned by Tornado

Tags: http, python-3.x, tornado, haproxy

I want to show an error to users of my web app. While handling a request, I might raise an [`HTTPError`](http://tornadokevinlee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/web.html#tornado.web.HTTPError) like this:

```
raise tornado.web.HTTPError(403, reason="You're not authorised")
```

When running it in my development environment, that results in a response status like this:

```
403 You're not authorised
```

But when I run it in production, I get:

```
403 Forbidden
```

Changing the [`serve_traceback` and `debug` options](http://tornadokevinlee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/web.html#tornado.web.Application.settings) doesn't help: the traceback is returned in the response body, but the status message is still just "Forbidden".

Why does it return the wrong message in production?

Tornado 4.1

Comment: Hm. In development I'm running behind an HAProxy instance. I suspect it's changing the response line. Should I not be using the response line for this information at all?

Comment: According to the [HTTP/1.1 spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html#sec6.1), the reason may be changed.

Comment: "In development" - I mean "In testing"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you running behind some sort of proxy that may be replacing this string?

In general you shouldn't be using the `reason` string for anything you care about. Proxies often replace it, browsers don't do anything with it, and in HTTP/2 it's completely removed. The main reason Tornado allows this string to be customized at all is that if you want to use a non-standard error code we have to put *something* there, so the `reason` argument is required if your status code is not in `httplib`.

In Tornado, `raise HTTPError(status)` is to be used when all you care about is the status. When you want to send a message, use this pattern instead:

```
self.set_status(403)
self.write("You're not authorized")
# or self.render("error.html", reason="You're not authorized"))
return
# or raise tornado.web.Finish() if you're too deep in the stack to return
```

Comment: Since I already have a lot of code that just raises an exception, I think I'll probably override `RequestHandler.send_error` instead and use a custom header field for the reason, and allow the default implementation of `write_error` to send the message back as HTML - so that I can still get full tracebacks in debug mode. Does that sound reasonable?

Comment: You'll probably think this is horrible, but it ended up being easier to override `set_status` to add a custom header containing the reason.

Comment: Indeed, it seems the proxy server (HAProxy) was changing the status line.